# React: Parent component refs not accessible to newly mounted child component?

Tags: javascript, scroll, reactjs, scrollbar

**What I'm doing:**

Simple - I need to scroll to the bottom of a message list as soon as the component contains it (`Messages`) is mounted.

**The Monkey Wrench In My Program :)**

Scrolling to bottom after mounting was fine until...

I simply moved some furniture around by taking the `header` of a scroll-able child component(`Messages`) and moved it into the it's parent component(`MessageSection`) in order to get the `header` to stick.

**Here is a BEFORE and an AFTER:**

Before(Yay it work!)
**MessageSection.js**

```
if(this.state.messages !== null) 
  return (
    <ScrollArea speed={0.8} className="area" contentClassName="content">
      <Messages  messages={this.state.messages} />
    </ScrollArea>
  );
}else{

  return (
    <ScrollArea speed={0.8} className="area" contentClassName="content">
      <EmptyMessages />
    </ScrollArea>
  );
}
```

The Simple Diff:

(Basically just moved the Heading of `Messages` into the parent `MessageSection`)

1. Pulled the header out of the scrolling child component(`Messages`).
2. Put the header above the ScrollArea
3. Then to render the new JSX -I  Wrapped the Header and ScrollArea in a new div ("messages")

**AFTER:(What! Y U NO Working??)**

**MessageSection.js**

```
if(this.state.messages !== null) {
  return (
    <div className="messages">
      <div className ="messages-section-header">
        <span className="header">{this.props.name}</span>
      </div>
      <ScrollArea speed={0.8} className="area scrollarea-flex" contentClassName="content">
        <Messages  messages={this.state.messages} />
      </ScrollArea>
    </div>
  );
}else{
  return (
    <div className="messages">
      <ScrollArea speed={0.8} className="area scrollarea-flex" contentClassName="content">
        <EmptyMessages />
      </ScrollArea>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**The Error:**

After the restructuring I got this error from [ScrollArea.jsx#L222](https://github.com/souhe/reactScrollbar/blob/master/src/js/scrollArea.jsx#L222)

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight'**

---

**The Cause of the Error:**

**When scroll-able component `Messages` mounts in it's `componentDidMount` it tries to scroll to the bottom using a exposed context of the `ScrollArea` component, but `refs` inside the `ScrollArea` do not exist. Which is weird because the `refs` will exist if called later by `componentDidUpdate`**

For Reference, here is the child component where the failure occurs.

**MessageList.js**(Scroll-able component that tries to scroll to bottom as it mounts)

```
contextTypes: {
  scrollArea: React.PropTypes.object //Used by the Library to Access the Scrolling Panel(The Parent Component)
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    this._scrollToBottom(); 
},

_scrollToBottom: function() {
    var scrollHeight = this.refs.messages.scrollHeight; 
    this.context.scrollArea.scrollYTo(scrollHeight);//ERROR -the refs will not exist inside context as expected
}
```

---

**Why I Am Baffled:**

**It doesn't make sense how `ScrollArea` can be mounted and that it's child `Messages` can also be mounted and calling the defined context `ScrollArea` exposed to it, yet the refs of `ScrollArea` don't exist???
Which is double confusing since it worked before I did the little change.**

Question:

How could a simple change in the structure of my code cause the context to not have access to it's refs

Comment: have you tried setting the refs [using a callback](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute)?

Comment: Just as an update I tried restructuring the code in a similar way as it was previously and the issue still exists. So a better explanation is that it previously was working on a fluke.

Comment: My best guess is that now that the scroll area is getting its height from flex-grow: 1; it must be some sort of mounting issue like @brandon explained in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A parent component is not "mounted" until after all of its children are "mounted".  So your `ScrollArea` is still in the process of "mounting" when your `Message` `componentDidMount` is executing.

Your problem is a result of the way you've modeled the interaction: You have a "child" component dictating behaviors of some parent components.  If you put your parent component in charge of this scroll behavior, then everything will work.

Specifically, add a `componentDidMount` method to your `MessageSection` component and put the logic there:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    // Assume you add `ref="messages"` to your render method so you can
    // get a reference to the child component
    this.refs.messages._scrollToBottom();
}
```

Comment: My gut totally agrees with you. The problem is that the author of the popular react-scrollbars kind of set you up needing to use context in a child component in order to access methods like _scrollToBottom. Here is a simple example https://github.com/souhe/reactScrollbar/blob/master/examples/changingChildren/js/app.jsx

Comment: yeah, notice my example code has `MessageSection` reaching down to the `MessageList` component to do the actual scrolling (via its context scrollbar...).

Comment: oh wow, very nice! Serious props(haha react pun not intended) for figuring that out in advance. Feels a little convoluted to dip back and forth that way. I don't understand why the author set it up that way.

Comment: probably new to React.  It took me a few months of working with React to break out of my old habits and just embrace props for information flow.

Comment: I'll switch everything out and tell you how it works out. If it does, I can't tell you how much of a god-send this answer was today. haha

Comment: your reasoning was right, but I'm finding that using componentDidMount to scroll to the bottom is complex if the scroll-able data is not immediately available. I'll give a list why.

Comment: 1)If I scroll to the bottom in the componentDidMount of the parent - my conditional rendering will try to scroll to the bottom of the EmptyMessages Filler component.

Comment: 2)If I try to render in the componentDidMount of the child then I'll have the original issue of the parent not being mounted for sizing.

Comment: 3)If I skip the conditional rendering and don't use EmptyMessages, then the size at componentDidMount could be zero because the list is empty.  oh man. haha